# jenkins/hudson can't connect to github repo

Tags: git, github, hudson, jenkins

I am on Ec2 with the base amazon ami linux- I have installed jenkins but when I go to pull the repo from github I am given the following error:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build social
Checkout:build social / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build social - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@5c7b21b
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@github.com:adulion/.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone git@github.com:adulion/.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:245)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1117)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1059)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:832)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:814)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1059)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1218)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:581)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:470)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1421)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:adulion/.git /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build social" returned status code 128:
stdout: Cloning into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build social...

stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have generated a key for the current user who installed jenkins and have managed to clone the repo using the git command line but jenkins can not.

I have copied the ~/.ssh files into /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh

I have added github to the known hosts and I have run out of solutions to try. Anyone know where I am going wrong? Is there a way to get jenkins to show the public key it's using and I can debug if it's using the correct one?

**I removed the name of the repo because its a private repo**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error seems to be: host key verification failed.

You should log into your Jenkins host as the Jenkins user and run:

```
ssh git@github.com
```

Then answer yes to the prompt about the host key. This only needs to be done once.

Alternatively you could add "StrictHostKeyChecking no" to ~jenkins/.ssh/config.

Comment: `ssh git@github.com` doesn't prompt about the host key, instead echoing _PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 / Hi ${NAME}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access._.  `StrictHostKeyChecking no`, however, worked like a charm.

Comment: I *think* adding github to the known_hosts will also work? ssh-keyscan -H http://github.com  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Comment: If your jenkins is headless, another convenient way is to ssh git@github.com from another user, and then copy the .ssh/know_hosts file to for example ~jenkins/.ssh/. Also make sure that you chown jenkins:jenkins to all the files in ~jenkins/.ssh

Comment: I have this issue trying connection to private GitLab repo. When I test connection from hos (Jenkins ver. 2.146 on docker) `ssh -T git@gitlab.domain.com` it successful but when Jenkins run build it still fail to fetch it. Suggestions above doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

1) Switch User into your jenkins account

```
su jenkins
```

2) Create the key without a passphrase

3) ssh git@github.com

That worked perfectly for me.

You may need to create a password for the jenkins account, if so use `sudo passwd jenkins`

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a single jenkins machine to check out multiple github repositories and had similar problems when setting it up.  What I ended up doing was configuring an SSH config file for jenkins so that SSH would automatically know which id file to associate with each repository.

/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config:

```
Host github-ABC
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa_ABC
```

In the Jenkins project config under source code management, I used this as the repository name:

```
git@github-ABC:user/repo.git
```

Finally, I use the SSH public key as a deploy key in the github repository.

Comment: do i need to load the config file somewhere?

Comment: No, SSH should automatically look at ~/.ssh/config when connecting.  [Documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

Answer (score 5):

He following helped me:

Login under Jenkins

```
sudo su jenkins
```

Copy your github key to Jenkins .ssh folder

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github* /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/
```

Raname the keys

```
mv id_rsa_github id_rsa
mv id_rsa_github.pub id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you log in as jenkins you can do

ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com

where ~/.ssh/id_rsa is the path/to/your/ssh/key and it will prompt for the password and add to the known_hosts file

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the ssh key of jenkins to you github user.

[Generate ssh key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Go to:

`Github->Settings(Top right)->SSH Keys(Left Pane)->Add SSH Key`