# Configuring Bitbucket and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I've been trying to get Jenkins to point to my private Bitbucket repo but when Jenkins attempts to access the repo, the following gets logged to my console:

```
Building in workspace /usr/local/hudson/.hudson/jobs/project/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /usr/local/hudson/.hudson/jobs/project/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@3d50e2
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision cec08812152ab1764ebb9bc52fbae2a6fe7c442d (origin/master)
Checkout:workspace / /usr/local/hudson/.hudson/jobs/project/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@3d50e2
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:username/projectname.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:852)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:839)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:821)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1218)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:586)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:475)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1438)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
```

I don't care how I connect to Bitbucket, I just want to see it work, and as this is just a quick trial, security isn't important to me.

I've tried getting Jenkins to connect via HTTPS with my username and password in the URL but I seem to get the same error.

Comment: What happens if you make your BitBucket repository a "public" one instead?

Comment: See also this similar (but less specific) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267964/configure-jenkins-to-connect-to-bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

If it's a MacOS X system you might probably find this useful:

[Configure Jenkins to connect to BitBucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267964/configure-jenkins-to-connect-to-bitbucket/13288065#13288065)